# How to train a convolutional neural net on images?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, guidelines

The functions `Predict[]` and `Classify[]` both have the option `Method -> "NeuralNetwork"`, but all the structure and code is hidden. I'm implementing a cnn or [convnet](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html) package, hopefully using `CUDALink`. Can anyone come up with a hello world example for a convnet on a set of annotated images to find logos? Here's the  [training set](http://image-net.org/download-imageurls) I'm using (a list of urls of the images in the training set).

Check out these links for more examples and related documentation:

- [A convnet running in your browser: convnetjs](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/)
- [Great site on deep learning](http://deeplearning.net/)

Comment: Your link `convnet` doesn't lead to a page about convnet, and your link `training set` doesn't link to a downloadable archive of images or the archive itself.

Comment: @Pickett Thanks! I just fixed the links, but you have to sign up to download the imagenet archive.

Comment: At this point in time Mathematica is not the most friendly platform for machine learning development. This is because, as you point out, most of its functionality is obscured.From the documentation, it isn't even easy to tell if the implementation supports sparse layer connectivity, or how you might specify that if it did, which you would need for your convolution neural network. Unless someone has done a fair amount of spelunking, a "hello world" example of the type you ask for might be a tall order.

Answer (score 10):

Mathematica doesn't currently have an implementation for training convolutional neural networks. This is certainly on our agenda of functionality to implement.

I will update this when I can give more information as to when this feature will become available.

Edit: If you are interested in third-party functionality, here is a Mathematica link to the Caffe deep learning library: https://github.com/Seilim/CaffeLink

Comment: Thanks, I know but was hoping for third party solutions

Comment: I added a third-party solution in the last edit.

Answer (score 4):

From Mathematica V11, there is built-in support for deep neural network(like convolutional neural network).

Check out introduction materials like [Image Recognition Using Deep Learning](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/image-and-signal-processing/image-recognition-using-deep-learning.html?product=mathematica) and [Accelerate Training Using a GPU](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/neural-networks/accelerate-training-using-a-gpu.html?product=language).