# Is there any decent deep learning library in Mathematica?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

[Deep Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning) is the currently trending method in machine learning community. Some languages like python and matlab have some very convenient toolbox for deep learning. So is there any decent deep learning library in Mathematica?

Comment: I don't know much about this topic but take a look at https://github.com/Seilim/CaffeLink

Comment: As @Szabolcs noted, there's an open-source library link to Caffe, a pretty decent implementation. I seem to recall a WRI staff comment that it is something they're working on (or thinking of working on... )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to train a convolutional neural net on images?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71574/how-to-train-a-convolutional-neural-net-on-images)

Comment: I can confirm that its something we are busy working on. 

What features would you like to see for this deep learning framework to be useful to you?

Comment: Not sure why this got closed.  I assume the OP was referring to third party packages at the time this was posted.  It seems like a reasonable question.

Comment: Just for your information, there will be soon a virtual conference, where it will be things on the Wolfram deep learning approach: https://www.wolfram.com/training/special-event/wolfram-virtual-conference-series/

Comment: Mathematica 11 has many aspects of Deep Learning covered.

Answer (score 1):

Finally from v11, there is built-in support for deep neural network.  [Image Recognition Using Deep Learning](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/image-and-signal-processing/image-recognition-using-deep-learning.html?product=mathematica).

And one can also use GPU to accelerate the process of deep neural network. [Accelerate Training Using a GPU](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/neural-networks/accelerate-training-using-a-gpu.html?product=language).